# Is it actually possible to complete every skill tree in Forbidden West?

Tags: horizon-forbidden-west

The question is simple: *Are there enough skill points in the game?*

I completed every main mission, side quest, errand, machine strike match, salvage contract, melee pit, hunting ground and arena challenge. And I end up short of like 4 skill points.

Then I found [this Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/horizon/comments/t97qxl/psa_missing_skill_points/):

> If the Arena icon when viewed from the map, or from standing in front of it, is not showing as green, complete a random legendary arena match and you'll just get the 4 missing points.

Which, essentially, is an exploit that let us farm skill points. I did it, and now I have 5 spare and I fear this can go on...

So, are we supposed to **miss** those 4 skill points? Or is it legitimately possible to complete every skill tree?

Comment: Have you played Burning Shores, or just the base game?

Comment: @Raj just the base game

Comment: Does your skill tree have the extra row at the bottom with things like Grapple Strike and Glide Targeting? I'm not sure if those where added by the big patch to the base game or by the Burning Shores DLC. Without the bottom row I thought there was easily enough skills.

Comment: @greg-449 new skills should be available only with the DLC purchased, which I don't own